# Acesso externo ao Wildfly - Erro 111: Connection refused

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Preciso de umas dica sobre como configurar meu servidor para ter acesso
de qualquer máquina dentro de minha rede. Estou fazendo testes no seguinte ambiente de desenvolvimento/testes:

Eclipse EE Luna SR2 em Java 8;

Servidor Wildfly 8.2.1 startado pelo Eclipse;

Em localhost minha aplicação roda beleza, mas quando tento acessar através de outra máquina dá o erro “O Sistema retorno erro 111: Connection refused”.
Já criei exceções no firewall(entrada e saída) para a porta 8080 e nada.
Meu standalone.xml está configurado assim:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <any-address />
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address />
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

O que mais preciso fazer ?
Obs.: Só desejo acesso de dentro de minha rede.

---

A parte final do log está assim :
14:47:53,849 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.2.Final
14:48:32,576 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
14:48:32,577 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016012: Deployment deployment "Sisprot.war" contains CDI annotations but no bean archive was found (no beans.xml or class with bean defining annotations).
14:48:32,610 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = Sisprot.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
14:48:32,853 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /Sisprot
14:48:32,912 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "Sisprot.war" (runtime-name : "Sisprot.war")
14:48:33,009 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
14:48:33,010 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
14:48:33,010 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" started in 41889ms - Started 270 of 325 services (92 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

Answer (score 0):

Nota: google tradutor

Você pode mudar isso

`<inet-address value ="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure: 0.0.0.0}"/>`

para isso

`<inet-address value ="125.126.127.133"/>`

Onde 125.126.127.133 é o endereço IP real do servidor. (também pode ser o nome do host)

Ou no script de inicialização ou se você estiver executando manualmente, adicione o argumento de ligação, p. Ex. `run.sh -b 125.126.127.133` ou `run.sh -b your.hostname.com`

Quando você tenta o `-b 125.126.127.133` ou`run.sh -b your.hostname.com` e se o Eclipse estiver iniciando o servidor, execute o seguinte:

> 1. Clique com o botão direito do mouse no servidor, selecione aberto.
> 2. Clique no link para "Abrir configuração de inicialização", primeiro hiperlink no canto superior esquerdo.
> 3. Adicione o `-b 125.126.127.133` ou` run.sh -b your.hostname.com 'logo após a última entrada no painel "Program Arguments" - certifique-se de colocar um espaço entre os argumentos.

Exemplo, o meu parecia assim

`-mp "C:/jboss-eap-7.0/modules" org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=C:\jboss-eap-7.0\standalone`

Mude para isso

`-mp "C:/jboss-eap-7.0/modules" org.jboss.as.standalone -b 125.126.127.133 --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=C:\jboss-eap-7.0\standalone`

Comment: @Ninja2112 - Essa resposta ajudou você?

Comment: .Fiz essa modificação, mas ainda continuo sem acesso.

Comment: Você pode adicionar o resultado do arquivo de log dos servidores à sua pergunta quando ele for totalmente iniciado, ele ajudará a identificar o problema. Além disso, você está iniciando o servidor através do Eclipse ou da linha de comando?

Comment: Iniciando o servidor através do Eclipse.

Comment: Atualizado a resposta na parte inferior, se isso não funcionar, você pode desligar o servidor, limpar a janela da consola, reiniciar o servidor e colar toda a saída do console (log), por favor?